# How to pass a string variable to .getElementById() in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I'm planning to use this code in a loop but I have to test it first.

Using the basic:

`doc.getElementById("product_basic_product_features_attributes_0_title").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AEG").Range("E2").Value`

I assign a value from my Sheet to an element ID *product_basic_product_features_attributes_0_title* on a webform.

Now I want to use a variable to contain 0 which should be incremented eventually in a loop. To test, I concatenated strings into tempStr variable to come up with *product_basic_product_features_attributes_0_title*, see code below. The variable is then used as the parameter in getElementbyID()

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim tempStr As String
tempStr = "product_basic_product_features_attributes_" & Str(i) & "_title"

doc.getElementById(tempStr).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AEG").Range("E2").Value
```

I'm getting an error on where I used the variable as parameter

> runtime error 91

tempStr is a string, it should be accepted by the method. Also, in my debugging, the value of tempStr is exactly the same as the element ID I used initially but it looks like, the error is because it's rejecting a use of variable in that parameter.

Comment: Did you mean to use CStr() and not Str() ?  They produce different results.  You could just do `tempStr = "product_basic_product_features_attributes_" & i & "_title"` and it should work fine.

Comment: Actually, as simple as not converting the value would fix it. Thanks you're right!

Comment: Looks like you decided to not to convert the value as a solution for this issue. I suggest you to post your solution as an answer and try to mark it as an answer after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments the method for VBA for string conversion is Cstr and is not needed though best practice for your use case.

```
doc.getElementById("product_basic_product_features_attributes_" & Cstr(i) & "_title").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AEG").Range("E2").Value
```

Though I suspect you want to alter the right hand side as well if using this in a loop.

Less efficient, but perhaps worth knowing, is that if you can accurately match on required elements with just the start id attribute value of `product_basic_product_features_attributes_` then you can gather a nodeList of all these ids and then index in during a loop (depends whether you also need the end *title* to accurately limit). Just a side note really.

```
Dim allElements As Object, i As Long

Set allElements = doc.querySelectorAll("[id^='product_basic_product_features_attributes_']")
For i = 0 To allElements.Length - 1
    allElements.Item(i).Value = "something..."
Next
```

[css attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IE and which OS you are using for making this test?

I tried to test the issue with Windows 7 and Windows 10 OS with IE 11 browser.

the difference I notice that code below is working fine on windows 7 but It is giving an error on Windows 10 machine. I tried various combination and also used Cstr() but nothing worked for Win 10. Not just in this scenario, in any condition it is not finding the element on the page.

Tested code:

```
Sub demo()

    '--Add reference to Microsoft Internet controls and Microsoft HTML Object library...

    Dim ie As Object
    Dim html As Object
    Dim obj As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim tempStr As String
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate2 "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\237.html"

    Do While ie.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop



For i = 0 To 9

    tempStr = "product_basic_product_features_attributes_" & i & "_title"
    Debug.Print (tempStr)

    Set obj = ie.document.getElementById(tempStr)

    obj.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2").Value

Next i


  '  Stop
   ' ie.Quit
   ' Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Output in win 7 with IE 11:

[image]

So if you are using Windows 10 OS than I suggest you to make a test on any other machine to check the difference in the result.